# https support between Wso2 servers

Tags: https, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have WSo2 ESB server in one Linux environment 
another WSo2 IS in another Linux environment

I'm using oauth token for validation, in the ESB axis2.xml I'm spicified

```
  <parameter name="oauth2TokenValidationService">https://identityserver:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService
```

But this request not reaching in IS side.  we temporarily need to use WSO2 https certificate (We don't have our own ssl certificate ).

In windows machine It working perfectly as we are adding Exception to certification. Please suggest any methodology to achieve this in  Linux environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This must work, If WSO2ESB and WSOIS are running in default self sign certificate.. However, I am not quite sure why we need to specific this url in axis2.xml file. It is fine to define the token validation url in the OAuth mediator. Did you seen any errors in the WSO2ESB console?